# Make Windows 7 apps with ionic

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, ionic-framework, electron, apache-cordova

Ionic can create UWP application which works on windows 8/10, but I want to create desktop app which works on windows 7 too. Electron can do that but that cannot work with android. I need to make a single app that works on Windows 7, Ubuntu and Android. On Visual Studio Community 2015

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard of [NW.js](https://nwjs.io/)? The apps you create run inside a chromium browser environment. I tested a app on windows10/ubuntu in the past. I think it'll run on windows 7 as well.

However you have to compile separately for each platform.

Build instructions for windows [is here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/windows_build_instructions.md#System-requirements).

**Note**: Nw.js cannot create Android or iOS apps. It can create desktop apps for Mac, Ubuntu and Windows.